# How to show this php script generated text inside this html input field?

Tags: php, html

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
     //Path of file
     $myFile = "test_file.txt";
     //Read file from array
     $lines = file($myFile);
     //Get number line of file
     $lineTotal = count($lines);
     //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
     $count = $lineTotal-1;
     //Get casual number
     $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
     //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
     echo $lines[$number_casual];
?>
```

This php code generates random texts from `test_file.txt` file.
I want to show the randomly generated texts by this php code inside this input field:

```
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="the text will be here" size="36">
```

**Update:**

Here is what I have tried but not working:
This one is showing a blank field:

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "test_file.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
 echo $lines[$number_casual];
?>
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ); ?>" size="36">
```

This one is also showing a blank field:

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "test_file.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
 echo $lines[$number_casual];
?>

<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo $lines[$number_casual]; ?>" size="36">
```

This one is crashing my page:

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "test_file.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
 echo '<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="' . htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ) . '" size="36">
?>

<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo $lines[$number_casual]; ?>" size="36">
```

My .txt file doesn't contain any special chars. It looks like this:

```
text1
text2
text3
```

Update 2:
Sorry everyone. I accidentally put wrong .txt file name in the php code so the field was blank. And this code worked:

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "random.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
?>
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ); ?>" size="36">
```

Comment: So put `$lines` in `value` attribute

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4446776/1675954 https://stackoverflow.com/a/20184680/1675954 https://stackoverflow.com/a/15832493/1675954  Tthese answers should be useful and could be adapted to your needs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to the value tag:

```
<?php
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "test_file.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
 echo $lines[$number_casual];
?>

<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo $lines[$number_casual]; ?>" size="36">
```

Comment: And what the `echo $lines[$number_casual];` prints to you?

Comment: Random texts from a .txt file

Comment: This solution works, unless you have special chars. You can try the @MonkeyZeus solution with `htmlentities()`.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your text file does not contain properly encode HTML content then you need to make sure to use `htmlentities()`

```
echo '<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="' . htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ) . '" size="36">';
```

or

```
<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="<?php echo htmlentities( $lines[$number_casual] ); ?>" size="36">
```

Comment: Both of them are not working. Please see my question updated.

Comment: @user8481790 Your `echo` is missing a closing single-quote and semicolon; this is a common syntax error. You can either fix the `echo` or just use my second example.

Answer (score 0):

Add the html to your echo.

```
 //Path of file
 $myFile = "test_file.txt";
 //Read file from array
 $lines = file($myFile);
 //Get number line of file
 $lineTotal = count($lines);
 //Remove 1 line (start from 0)
 $count = $lineTotal-1;
 //Get casual number
 $number_casual = rand(0,$count);
 //Print line 2 ([0] = 1 ; [1] = 2 ; ...)
 echo '<input name="accesspin" style="width: 300px" value="' . $lines[$number_casual]; . '" size="36">';
```